# Qualitative or quantitative?

Tags: qualitative

If I went through a box of candy which contains 4 types of flavor (orange, grape, apple, strawberry) and recorded the number of each flavor in my worksheet, what is the type of data that it is involved: qualitative or quantitative?

I was very confused, that the flavor have 4 categories, which is categorical variable. When I count each of the types of flavor and record the result in a nice table, it looks like that it is quantitative data. Can someone explain this to me? Thank you.

Comment: Is this a home work?

Comment: no, i just confused whether the variable flavor is quantitative or qualitative.

Answer (score 1):

I see **two** *variables*, which could immediately be recognized in your box of candy example - *flavor* and *number of candies* of a particular flavor. Flavor is a *categorical variable* (*nominal* scale) and number of candies is a *numeric variable* (*ratio* scale). According to the established *theory of measurement*, based on work by S. Stevens (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_of_measurement), flavor is to be categorized as a *qualitative* variable, while number of candies is a *quantitative* one.